# Xamarin Studio / MonoDevelop T4 pre-build

Tags: t4, xamarin-studio

Is there a way, with Xamarin Studio, to have a pre build command that runs a T4 template?
This would help generating a C# file on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here is the solution if somebody is interested:

Just create a mono-t4 file in your solution folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
mono /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe -o $1 $2
```

Don't forget to make it executable with

```
chmod +x mono-t4
```

Then in your project options, in "Custom commands" add a "Before-Build" command.
Command is:

```
${SolutionDir}/mono-t4 YourOutputCSharpFile.cs ${ProjectDir}/YourInputT4.tt
```

Then everytime you will compile you will get your csharp file up to date.

Comment: This looks like a valid answer from yourself. You should `accept` it.

Comment: Yes you are right Stephane, currently I don't have enough reputation so I can't do it but I will some hours and do it when I can.

Comment: The path to TextTransform.exe happened to be changed since '13. On Mac OS X 10.10.3 with mono 4.0 it seems to point to:

`/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe`