# Can I use T4 Text Generation in Xamarin.iOS Projects?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, t4

I would love to use [Run-Time Text Generation with T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee844259.aspx) in my Xamarin.iOS project (also known as MonoToch). Unfortunately the generated .cs file depends on System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerErrorCollection which seems to be part of the System.dll for iOS (the whole System.CodeDom namespace is missing).

How can I work around the issue?

Comment: I have seen some other people doing it, so it should be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575019/xamarin-studio-monodevelop-t4-pre-build

Comment: The question you have linked only asks about Xamarin Studio and T4. This is working out of the box. My problem is that the generated .cs file can not be compiled because it has a CompilerErrorCollection field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin.iOS platform does not support runtime code generation and therefore excluded the whole `System.CodeDom` namespace. But the T4 stuff is done by Xamarin Studio, so what worked for me was to copy the files [CompilerError.cs](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.CodeDom.Compiler/CompilerError.cs) and [CompilerErrorCollection.cs](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.CodeDom.Compiler/CompilerErrorCollection.cs) from the Mono repository into my Xamarin.iOS project.

Comment: unfortunately your links are dead now